# laravel functions inside external files

Tags: php, laravel

For example, there is this file -> project/public/file.php and I have my own reasons to put it here.

How can I get laravel's functions to work inside this file? renaming it to file.blade.php didn't do the trick.

More specifically, I tried `{{ Form::token(); }}` in that file.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `project/public/file.php` a view file or does it have another purpose?

Comment: I can't say that it's really a view file. It is callback file, which retrieves information from external sites API. I put it here, because in that external sites API I needed to put path to my callback file. And I can't put views path here :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can boot laravel from an external script simply by requiring laravel's bootsrap file and the composer autoload files.

```
<?php 

// boot laravel
require __DIR__ .'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$laravel_app = require __DIR__ .'/../bootstrap/start.php';
$laravel_app->boot();
```

You can then call most of laravel's mojo from there.

Edit: By the sound of it, you want a script of some sort that can be executed. You're best off utilizing laravel's CLI artisan and write your own command.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands

Comment: Thanks.

Requiring autoload and start files was exactly what I needed :)